# View not updating after a property in ViewModel is updated

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

So I'm trying to implement a ListBoxItem that has a TextBlock that binds to a property in the viewmodel. But for some reason the view isn't being updated even after the viewmodel property is updated. Can anyone give me some pointers?

In the view (xaml)

```
<phone:Pivot HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="748" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Title="pivot" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460">
    <StackPanel x:Name="POIStackPanel" DataContext="{StaticResource POIViewModel}">
        <ListBoxItem x:Name="SelectedPOIItem">        
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPickupPOI.label}" />
        </ListBoxItem>

        phone:PivotItem x:Name="GooglePivot" Header="Google">
                                <ListBox x:Name="GooglePOIList" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding GooglePOICollection}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                    Height="441" 
                                    Width="436"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPickupPOI, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource POIItemTemplate}" />
                            </phone:PivotItem>
    </StackPanel>
</phone:Pivot>
```

In the viewmodel

```
public ObservableCollection<PointOfInterest> GooglePOICollection { get; private set; }

public PointOfInterest SelectedPickupPOI
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedPickupPOI;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedPickupPOI = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedPickupPOI");
    }
}

public PointOfInterestViewModel()
{
    this.GooglePOICollection = = new ObservableCollection<PointOfInterest>();
    this.SelectedPickupPOI = new PointOfInterest();
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (null != handler)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My PointOfInterest Models

```
public abstract class PointOfInterest : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public abstract string id { get; set; }
    public abstract string label { get; set; }
}

public class GooglePOI : PointOfInterest
{
    private string _label;

    public override string label
    {
        get { return _label; }
        set
        {
            _label = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("label");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
so I found out that if I do `_selectedPickupPOI.label = value.label;` it will update the view correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you update the property?

Comment: Are you getting it's initial value?

Comment: Have you tried <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPOI}" /> - you are rising a property SelectedPOI and look for SelectedPOI.label in texblock.

Comment: I've updated my code to show more information. @Romasz Can you clarify?

Comment: @user1043625 After update I see binding Path. One guess I have: have you tried changing UpdateSourceTrigger Text="{Binding SelectedPickupPOI.label, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}

Comment: @Romasz I'm getting an error that says requested value PropertyChanged is not found

Comment: @Romasz I've once again updated my OP. Can you be kind enough to take another look at it?

Comment: @user1043625 Unfortunately I don't get it and I'm not able to explain you what you are exacly doing wrong. It seems to me that when you _selectedPickupPOI.label = value.label then NotifyPropertyChanged("label") is fired and textblock is updated. Maybe adding NotifyPropertyChanged("label") after NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedPickupPOI") could also help.